# Можно ли внутри JavaScript как-то использовать функции php?

Tags: php, javascript

Мне нужно сделать примерно следующее:
при нажатии на кнопку вылазит окошко подтверждения (confirm()) с вариантами "ок/отмена". При нажатии на кнопку ок, должна выполняться php функция mysql_query.
Как это можно реализовать?
есть код скрипта

```
<script>
function del_post($num) {
  x=confirm("Вы действительно хотите удалить пост?");
  if (x==true) {
 **---- ВОТ ТУТ ДОЛЖЕН БЫТЬ mysql_query! ----**
        if($dq) {
        alert('Пост успешно удалён');
                }
        else alert('Произошла ошибка при удалении');
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[XMLHttpRequest](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest)

> XMLHTTP (XMLHttpRequest, XHR) — API, доступное в скриптовых языках браузеров, таких как JavaScript. Использует запросы HTTP или HTTPS напрямую к веб серверу и загружает данные ответа сервера напрямую в вызывающий скрипт.[1](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) Информация может передаваться в любом текстовом формате, например, в XML, HTML или JSON. Позволяет осуществлять HTTP-запросы к серверу без перезагрузки страницы.

Comment: не очень пока шарю в js...
надеюсь, я правильно понял, и мне надо использовать это?
send(content) Отправляет запрос на сервер.
вместо контента можно сделать mysql_query?

Comment: Нет, не правильно. После нажатия кнопки "Ок" Вам необходимо отправить синхронный запрос к php скрипту, который выполнит необходимый запрос к mysql БД. Если это слишком сложно - попробуйте после нажатия кнопки "Ок" сделать переадресацию страницы на скрипт, который выполнит нужный запрос, а после вернет пользователя на ту же страницу.